# Property setter doesn't update the backing field

Tags: c#, properties

I always thought that property is something like shortcut for methods. However this example makes me strange. It seems to me that functions changePropertyId and changeMethodId do the same. However reality is different. Only second one works properly. Can somebody can explain it?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        User user = new User();
        user.changePropertyId(1);
        Console.Write(user.Id);
        user.changeMethodId(1);
        Console.Write(user.Id);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class DBObject
{
    private int mId;
    public int Id { set { mId = Id; } get { return mId; } }
    public void setId(int aId)
    {mId = aId;}
}

public class User : DBObject
{
    public void changePropertyId(int aId) { Id = aId; }
    public void changeMethodId(int aId) { setId(aId); }
}
```

The result from first function is 0, from second is 1. My intention was to get 1 from both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically they should do the same in your sample. However, there is a little mistake in the property's implementation that you need to correct to make it work:

```
public int Id { set { mId = value; } get { return mId; } }
```

`value` is a reserved name for the parameter of the property setter that contains the new value that should be assigned to the property.

Answer (score 5):

You have a bug here:

```
set { mId = Id; }
```

This should read:

```
set { mId = value; }
```

The `value` is the new `value` which you should use in a property
setter. Due to this bug basically your setter has no effect.

Here is the fixed version.

```
public class DBObject
{
    private int mId;
    public int Id { set { mId = value; } get { return mId; } }
    public void setId(int aId) { mId = aId; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This line is wrong:

```
public int Id { set { mId = Id; } get { return mId; } }
```

You're assigning the current property value to the backing field in the setter so you're not actually changing the value.  That should read:

```
public int Id { set { mId = value; } get { return mId; } }
```

That said, if you're not going to add any code to the getter or setter other than that to return the backing field and set the backing field then you should do away with the backing field altogether and just do this:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Note there that I have put the getter before the setter, which is a universal convention and something that you should do too.

Answer (score 0):

Your setter is Invalid: it should be `mId = value;`. `value` is a special variable used in setter which contains the value to set.